# How to get TX/RX using shell script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a script and I need to modify this so it can get the TX/RX bytes.

```
#!/bin/bash    
echo "$HOSTNAME, timestamp=$( date +%s ), cat /proc/net/dev" >> "system_monitor.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to obtain the RX and TX bytes count for the interface `$interface` from `/proc/net/dev`:

```
</proc/net/dev grep -oP "$interface"':\s*\K\d+'            # RX bytes
</proc/net/dev grep -oP "$interface"':\s*(\d+\s+){8}\K\d+' # TX bytes
```

This prints the first or respectively ninth number from the line containing “`$interface`:”.

Comment: When I put this in my script using echo, it prints the whole command in the file and it does not do anything.

Comment: @Onyic try it without `echo` and with redirection: `</proc/net/dev grep -oP "$interface"':\s*\K\d+' >>system_monitor.csv`